# I want to Fetch the text with dynamic number

Tags: java, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to assert the text with dynamic number at the end of text.

ex.

> There is no direct mechanism in selenium to identify the PDF of extract the data of pdf, 
>   To achieve this functionality you can write your custom code in C# to read the PDF (123) 234-2345.

I am able to fetch the text. But how do I assert it as the number part i.e `(123) 234-2345`?

Things that I have tried:

```
Regex regularExpression = new Regex(@"There is no direct mechanism in selenium to identify the PDF of extract the data of pdf, 
To achieve this functionality you can write your custom code in C# to read the PDF(\d{3}) \d{3}-\d{4}.");
validateText =  (_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[@id='provider-account-credentials']//div[@class='row']")).Text).Replace("\r\n","");
Assert.IsTrue(regularExpression.IsMatch(validateText));
```

Problem:
`regularExpression.IsMatch(validateText)` is retruning false.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason is (probably) the texts are not exact match. You can use `Contains()` for a partial match as well.

```
Regex regularExpression = new Regex(@"There is no direct mechanism in selenium to identify the PDF of extract the data of pdf, 
To achieve this functionality you can write your custom code in C# to read the PDF(\d{3}) \d{3}-\d{4}.");
validateText =  (_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[@id='provider-account-credentials']//div[@class='row']")).Text).Replace("\r\n","");
Assert.IsTrue(regularExpression.Contains(validateText));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your regular expression you use '(' & ')' char. This char is used [to capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).
You have to escape them:

```
There is no direct mechanism in selenium to identify the PDF of extract the data of pdf, To achieve this functionality you can write your custom code in C# to read the PDF \(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}.
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: escaping did not work. I still get **false** in  `regularExpression.IsMatch(validateText)`

Comment: It works fine in my case, did you try to print `validateText` ? I used `Regex regularExpression = new Regex(@"There is no direct mechanism in selenium to identify the PDF of extract the data of pdf, To achieve this functionality you can write your custom code in C# to read the PDF \(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}.");`